# I want to save my pandas DataFram as an image ( any format or as a PDF file ). the size of my dataframe is a little big ( 70x70)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, image

I want to save my pandas DataFram as an image ( any format or  as a PDF file ). The size of my DataFrame is a little big ( 70x70). I got an error like this:

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import dataframe_image as dfi

# pd.set_option('display.max_cols', -1)
pd.set_option('display.max_column', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', -1)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

df = pd.DataFrame(conf_mat,columns = list(np.arange(0,70,dtype = int)))

df_styled = df.style.background_gradient() #adding a gradient based on values in cell
dfi.export(df,"table.pdf",table_conversion = 'matplotlib')
```

I got the following Error:

ValueError: Your DataFrame has more than 30 columns and will produce a huge image file, possibly causing your computer to crash. Override this error by explicitly setting `max_cols`. Use -1 for all columns.

Please let me know if there is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the help documents of the dataframe_image.export.
I set the maximum columns to -1 and also set the table_conversion to 'chrome'
like this:

```
dfi.export(df_styled,'table.png',max_cols = -1,table_conversion = 'chrome')
```

I got some warnings but it worked!